# Разбить строку через выравнивание по ширине

Tags: java

Есть разделитель равный 10, и большая строка. Необходимо разбить строку по разделителю, переносить слова нельзя, если слово больше разделителя, его нужно перенести на новую строку.

Comment: Не очень ясен вопрос. Что такое `разделитель равный 10`? Строка `10`? Или число символов? И если да, то каких? И что значит `слово`? С предлогом через дефис будет считаться? И что значит `перенести на новую строку`? Добавить в строку символ переноса строки? Если да, то в каком виде? `\n`, `\n\r`, `</br>`? С такой постановкой вопроса вам мало что можно ответить. Проясните все детали и покажите исходный текст и что должно из него получиться. Опишите ваши попытки задачу решить и что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вроде всё понятно, кроме того, как [это](https://ideone.com/3nWanW) на джаву переписать - [нифига не работает](https://ideone.com/yCsWEQ) - проблемы с юникодом :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, нифига себе) , конечно, представлял, что регулярками многое можно, но вот чтобы настолько... Как на яву такое перенести сам не знаю(

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще задача похожа на [Text Justification](https://leetcode.com/problems/text-justification/), разве что без дополнительных пробелов, что делает задачу ещё проще.

Comment: @tym32167, а у меня ассоциации с отображением текста в СМС. Только не хватает пункта, что слова длиннее 10 символов всё же надо разрывать по 10, но это легко делается заменой `{11,}` на `{10}`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ура! Я нагуглил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, круто) Жаль только, что без поллитры не знакомому с регулярками человеку будет сложно разобраться что происходит)))

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/yCsWEQ

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String s = "Здравствуйте есть разделитель равный 10, и большая строка. Необходимо разбить строку по разделителю, переносить слова нельзя, если слово больше разделителя его нужно перенести на новую строку.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:(\\w{10,})|(.{1,10})(?!\\w))\\s*", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    System.out.print(p.matcher(s).replaceAll("$1$2\n"));
  }
}
```

Если длинные слова надо резать на части по 10 символов, просто удали запятую :)